# Check string for words starting with the character @

Tags: php

Hi there and thank you for taking the time to look into this.

I'm working on a comment system and instead of using nested comments, I just want to add the @user method for replies.

So let's say for example I enter this comment:

```
@moonwalker: Thanks again for your reply.
```

I'm looking for a function to check if a word is starting with the character @ and after that changing the word into a link. The problem I'm facing is that people will use things like:

```
@moonwalker: rest of the message

@moonwalker, rest of the message

@moonwalker rest of the message
```

or even use en email address in their comments.

Is there a simple way to achieve this? Preg_match perhaps?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I guess use preg_match, and also find the longest match that actually matches a username in the database. to prevent interference from email, don't allow a character before the @

Comment: I don't know PHP but if it has any support for Regular Expressions then you could use a RegEx like `^@(w/)*$` . That would match a string starting with an '@', then any number of characters [A-Z 0-9], then you could use the string returned from whatever function you use to do what you want with it such as turn it into a link. Does that help?

Comment: Check out some of the [regex tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world) that might help you test or design a preg_match expression.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help! I will certainly check the regex tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function:

```
preg_replace('/(@\w+)/', '<a href=\'#\'>\1</a>', $comment);
```

Comment: Thanks a million. This worked fine, but it also made a link of the last part of an email address. I'll try to update your code. :)

Comment: require the char before the @ to be something other than a-z or 0-9 and you should be safe from email addresses.

Comment: hmm...regex is absolutely not my speciality. I tried everything, but nothing works so far. I'll choose this answer as my accepted answer, but I still need to disable the email addresses. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Ok...I just used a little hack to solve this. I added a white space before the start of the message and used this regular expression:
`code` preg_replace('/(\s\@\w+)/', '<a href=\'#\'>\1</a>', $message); `/code`

It works fine now, but I still think there is a better solution for this.

Comment: Found it:
preg_replace('/(^@\w+)/', '<a href=\'#\'>\1</a>', $message)

Hope this will help someone else looking for the same.

Thanks again all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use preg_match. I haven't tested it, but i suppose it would be something like :

```
preg_match("/^\@/", $message)
```

However, i strongly advice you to reconsider the protocol. It's much better to add non printable characters and more than 1 byte. For instance, a stub like "0x1 0x12 0x03 0x07".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your preg_match doesn't work unfortunately. Can you please provide me more explanation about the non printable characters? Thanks!

Comment: sorry about it, the thing is that to write a reg you have to try it. I guess i might be missing the rest text matching, like "/^\@\w+" maybe.

Comment: actually, i didn't understand that this is a twitter like implementation, i thought you were talking about the protocol of communication. So, printable characters do not apply here.

Comment: Oh...I never used twitter before. I'm just not into it. I had the idea without even knowing it already exists somewhere. Thanks for pointing that out. :)